# Chromium column layout and overflow hidden hides text

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, microsoft-edge, chromium

I'm having problems using the column layout together with overflow hidden in chromium. The first entries in all columns except the first one are missing their text. The following code snippet is a minimalized example. In reality I'd use `ul` together with `li` where the same problems occur. The column layout is used, because it is unknown how many elements there will be or how much width there is available overall.

```css
.list {
  width: 14em;
  column-width: 4em;
}

.elem {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="elem">First entry</div>
  <div class="elem">Second entry</div>
  <div class="elem">Third entry</div>
  <div class="elem">Fourth entry</div>
  <div class="elem">Fifth entry</div>
  <div class="elem">Sixth entry</div>
</div>
```

A "solution" to this problem seems to be adding `transform: translateZ(0);` to the list elements like following:

```css
.list {
  width: 14em;
  column-width: 4em;
}

.elem {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  transform: translateZ(0);
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="elem">First entry</div>
  <div class="elem">Second entry</div>
  <div class="elem">Third entry</div>
  <div class="elem">Fourth entry</div>
  <div class="elem">Fifth entry</div>
  <div class="elem">Sixth entry</div>
</div>
```

But I'm not believing, that this should be the final solution. This is a mere 'hack' to make it somehow work.

This problem occurs in google chrome and in the new microsoft edge browsers (which both use the chromium engine)

So my questions are: What is the real problem here, and how do I do this properly?

Comment: Both your examples look _absolutely_ the same for me, in a current Chrome (84.0.4147.105 on 64bit Win 10)

Comment: I had version 84.0.4147.89 64bit Win 10 before. It just now updated to  84.0.4147.105 and I am still seeing differences. This is what I am seeing: http://prntscr.com/tpvjet

Comment: I tested and reproduced the issue in chromium. It works well in Edge Legacy and IE. I think this should be an issue with Chrome and Edge Chromium. You could Report an issue (Alt+Shift+I) in Chrome or Send feedback (Alt+Shift+I) in Edge Chromium. For now, you can use your solution or Baro's solution as an workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Also `backface-visibility: hidden;` performs the same trick. Probably because GPU rendering is forced. It is probably a bug.

```css
.list {
  width: 14em;
  column-width: 4em;
}

.elem {

  backface-visibility: hidden;

  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="elem">First entry</div>
  <div class="elem">Second entry</div>
  <div class="elem">Third entry</div>
  
  <div class="elem">Fourth entry</div>
  <div class="elem">Fifth entry</div>
  <div class="elem">Sixth entry</div>
</div>
```

By doing some tests I found an alternative that does not force rendering on the GPU.
Using: `border: solid 0.1px transparent;`
Personally I would prefer it.

Unfortunately I can't tell you the reason for this bug, I don't even know if it can be considered an answer but more as a suggestion.

```css
.list {
  width: 14em;
  column-width: 4em;
}

.elem {

  border: solid 0.1px transparent;

  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="elem">First entry</div>
  <div class="elem">Second entry</div>
  <div class="elem">Third entry</div>
  
  <div class="elem">Fourth entry</div>
  <div class="elem">Fifth entry</div>
  <div class="elem">Sixth entry</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice to have an alternative :)